# Retrieving data using URLSession and ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mvvm, swiftui

I'm attempting to retrieve data for a user profile, and I'm not sure how to initialize the observable objects in my view model. I see a lot of examples of where an array of objects will be returned, but not one single object.

How can I initialize the `profile` variable in the view model with a null value before I attempt to fetch the profile data, or should I not use this method for retrieving this data?

Also on a side note, is it best practice to write a common class (like a RestManager class) to handle all API requests and have one method which invokes the URLSession dataTaskPublisher method?

Model:

```swift
struct Profile: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var address: String
    var city: String
    var emailAddress: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var smsNumber: String
    var state: String
    var userBio: String
    var username: String
    var zipCode: Int
}
```

ViewModel:

```swift
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // Cannot create Profile() as it needs data to be instantiated
    @Published var profile: Profile = Profile()

    init() {
        fetchProfile()
    }

    func fetchProfile() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://path/to/api/v1/profiles") else {
            print("Failed to create URL")
            return
        }
        
        let requestData = [
            "username": "testuser"
        ]
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(requestData)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .tryMap { output in
                guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                    throw HTTPError.statusCode
                }

                return output.data
            }
            .decode(type: Profile.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .retry(3)
            .replaceError(with: Profile()) // Same issue here - requires data to be instantiated
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$profile)
    }
}
```

View:

```swift
struct ProfileSummary: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProfileViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(viewModel.profile.firstName)
                Text(viewModel.profile.lastName)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Profile")
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.fetchProfile()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution – to avoid optionals – is a static property with creates an empty sample instance

```
struct Profile: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var address: String
    var city: String
    var emailAddress: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var smsNumber: String
    var state: String
    var userBio: String
    var username: String
    var zipCode: Int

    static let sample = Profile(id: UUID(), address: "", city: "", emailAddress: "", firstName: "", lastName: "", smsNumber: "", state: "", userBio: "", username: "", zipCode: 0)
}
```

and use it

```
@Published var profile = Profile.sample
```

and also in the `replaceError` operator line

```
.replaceError(with: Profile.sample)
```

---

Or create an enum for all possible states for example

```
enum State {
    case undetermined
    case isLoading
    case loaded(Profile)
    case error(Error)
}

@Published var state : State = .undetermined
```

In the view `switch` on the state and render appropriate UI

Side notes:

- If the struct members are never going to be modified declare them as constants (`let`)
- `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` is pointless if the pipeline ends in the same scope.

Comment: It seems to be easier with an empty sample, but
I feel this is why Optionals were invented, to avoid having to 
write data that is not true. It's better to have "nil = does not exist".
In the UI as well, you may have something like this. 
"Text(profile.firstName).frame(width: 111).border(.red)". 
This will show an empty red box.

Comment: According to your design the empty instance is supposed to be a placeholder. If you expect *does not exist* you should **not** replace the error and handle it properly. For example you could return a `Result<Profile,Error>` type. Or use an enum with multiple states. In SwiftUI you are encouraged to avoid optionals as much as possible, more than in Objective-C bridged UIKit.

Comment: After reviewing all of the answers and doing some testing, I was able to get it working using this method. I found this link which complemented this post as well: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/handling-loading-states-in-swiftui/. Thank you to everyone that responded!

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this, making "Profile" an optional:

(Note, in your "ProfileViewModel", I can't see where you actually assign a value to "profile". Seems you are missing the sink/receiveValue)

```
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var profile: Profile: Profile?  // <--- here
    ...
}
   
struct ProfileSummary: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProfileViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if let profile = viewModel.profile {  // <--- here
                    Text(profile.firstName)
                    Text(profile.lastName)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Profile")
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.fetchProfile()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: to fix your other problems in "ProfileViewModel", you could try:

```
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var profile: Profile?
    
    var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func fetchProfile() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://path/to/api/v1/profiles") else {
            print("Failed to create URL")
            return
        }
        
        let requestData = ["username": "testuser"]
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(requestData)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest(url: url))
            .tryMap { output in
                guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                    throw HTTPError.statusCode
                }
                return output.data
            }
            .decode(type: Profile.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .retry(3)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
             .sink { completion in
                 print("-----> completion: \(completion)")
             } receiveValue: { profile in
                 self.profile = profile
             }
            .store(in: &self.cancellable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Missed that part. I was rewriting this code and forgot to add it. It's updated now with what I was doing before. Looks like I still have an issue with .replaceError and .assign. With .assign, it doesn't allow me to use an optional.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with "replaceError" and "assign()", maybe you could use: 
".replaceError(with: nil)" and replace ".assign(to: &$profile)" with ".sink { error in
              // deal with the error
           } receiveValue: { profile in
              self.profile = profile
           }"

Comment: updated the answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: cannot find HTTPError in scope. Can you expose the enum?

Comment: I could not find `HTTPError` either, 
 you could try using `URLError(.badServerResponse)` or simply `throw response.statusCode`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting a view attempt to render content that does not exist (how the heck can that be implemented anyway??)

**specify *clearly* what to render *at any time*.**

So, instead of attempting to draw an optional whose value is `.none`:

Your "view state" or a part of it:

```
enum Content {
    case none(NoContent) 
    case some(Profile)
}
```

In your View Model:

```
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewState: Content = .none(NoContent())
    ...
```

Your `NoContent` represents exactly what to render when the profile value is absent. This also enables you to render a nice representation for "no profile available (yet)" since you can render *any* view you (or UX) wants to look at when you are about to load the profile - or when an error occurred, or ...